# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Get text inside <td> tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

So I have this .html file that I have to analyze. In that file I have lines like this one:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=1 rowspan=1 bgcolor=#ffffff align=left valign=top>
        <font size=1 face="Tahoma" color=#000000>
            <nobr>
                 240,0000
            </nobr>
        </font>
    </td>

     <td colspan=1 rowspan=1 bgcolor=#ffffff align=left valign=top>
        <font size=1 face="Tahoma" color=#000000>
            <nobr>
                 340,0000
            </nobr>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I need to get is 240,0000 , 340,0000 and so on. I have tried something like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('File.html');

foreach($html->find('td') as $element) 
   echo $element->text. '<br>';
```

Doing it this way I don't get the text I want to get.

How can I make reference to the text inside  tag? So I can get the values.

Comment: does `$html->find('nobr')` not work for you? Or is it not always formatted the same?

Comment: what do I echo after that to get the text?

Comment: `$element->paintext` ^^

Comment: Got it, but you're missing a letter: $element->plaintext
I guess it was a typo :)

Comment: hahaha, yeah, twas a typo. =]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing like `$element->text` Use `$element->plaintext`

```
foreach ( $html->find('td nobr') as $element ) {
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```