# Preg split table all tds

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to get all occurrences of tds in a string. At the moment im using `$tds = preg_split( '#(?=<td>)#', $toDisplayNotes );`

but this does not get all the tds. is it possible to produce an array that looks like this:

```
array {
  [0] => "<td>hello</td>"
  [1] => "<td align="right">world</td>"
  [2] => "<td>another td</td>"
}
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/247702)

Comment: @Stijn, i don't really have a choice, unless there is a better way?

Comment: From the top answer on that question: Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: @rob: [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument)... there is a better way, so you have a choice!

Comment: Or look at [this question an it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822908/php-simple-html-dom-get-text-inside-td-tag) using "simple html dom".

Comment: thanks guys, ill try and work out a solution based on your comments

Comment: @rob: Do look into the suggestions and links in my answer, as it might help you on your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `DOMDocument` class, you can easily get all cells like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$contents = array();
foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    $contents[] = $cell->nodeValue;
}
var_dump($contents);
```

The `$cells` var is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/DOMNodeList), so it has some methods that you might be able to use. The `$cell` variable will be assigned a particular instance of [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/DOMNode) on each iteration, which has all sorts of methods/properties that could be useful for your use-case, too (like `getAttribute`)
Looking at your question, though, you'll be wanting the outer html (including the tags) in your array. Now that's easy:"

```
$markup = array();
foreach($cells as $cell)
{
    $markup[] = $dom->saveXML($cell);
}
```

Side-note:
Perhaps a `for` loop will be more performant than `foreach`. I haven't tested/compared the two, but you could try if you see a difference the approach above and this one:

```
$markup = array();
for($i=0, $j = $cells->length;$i<$j;$i++)
{
    $markup[] = $dom->saveXML($cells->item($i));
}
```

The reason why I'm using `saveXML` and not `saveHTML` is simple: `saveHTML` will generate a *valid* DOM (including opening `<html>` tags and what have you). Not what you want. That's why `saveXML` is, in this case, the better choice.
A slightly related question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840683/echo-innerhtml-without-outer-node-tags)

Comment: @rob: `$cell->value` should have been `$cell->nodeValue` (as you can see on the man page of the `DOMNode` class)... corrected my mistake. That and the warnings you included in your comment just tell me that you're not passing the right variables/types to the methods. I'm just using example vars, you might want to check what it is you're passing to `loadHTML`, for example